# Implement filesystem access on USB storage devices under Android

Tags: android, filesystems, usb-mass-storage

I'd like to access some files on a SDcard using a modern Android phone (e.g. Nexus 5).

Since the SDcard slot is missing on modern phones usually, I found a solution in using a USB SDcard adapter. Unfortunately Android isn't mounting the connected device automatically, but an app called "Nexus Media Importer" as well as an usb plugin for the Total commander app is able to mount it and allow access to the files.

Does anyone know how they did it? Are there some open-source libraries available maybe?

Comment: One thing: I'm not able to use root - it has to be a solution without root rights.

Comment: Here is the link: https://github.com/mjdev/libaums

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android detect usb storage for kitkat (4.4)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208297/android-detect-usb-storage-for-kitkat-4-4).  There I posted solutions for pre-6.0 and 6.0/above.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have root permissions for executing this kind of operation. However, in order to see which partitions are mounted or available on your device look inside `/etc/vold.fstab`.

To read `/etc/vold.fstab` you do not need root permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote such a framework as my bachelors thesis, you can find it here: https://github.com/mjdev/libaums

support_ms already mentioned it, thanks.

If you have further questions, do not hesitate to ask!